# How to exclude a stylesheet from being used for a certain template in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

How do I exclude a .css file from being used for a specific template in Meteor.js?  I have multiple files for different styled templates.

Comment: You can't really. Since this is a SPA, all of the CSS is bundled together. There are several structured approaches for CSS namespacing, but generally you need to namespace your CSS hooks and selectors (tag-class-id combinations) in a way that they don't interfere with one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `ecmascript` package, you can control the [import of css](https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#css-importing) files the same way you do with javascript files.